# Airflow + Docker: Path behaviour (+Repo)

Tags: python, docker, path, airflow

I have difficulties to understand how the paths in airflow work. I created this repository so that it is easy to see what I mean: https://github.com/remo2479/airflow_example/blob/master/dags/testdag.py
I created this repository from scratch according to the manual on the airflow page. I just deactivated the example DAGs.

As you can see in the only DAG (**dags/testdag.py**) the DAG contains two tasks and one variable declaration using an opened file.
The two tasks are using the dummy sql script in the repository (**dags/testdag/testscript.sql**). One time i used testdag/testscript.sql as path (task 1) and one time dags/testdag/testscript.sql (task 2). With a connection set up task 1 would work and task 2 wouldnt because the template cannot be found. This is how I would expect both tasks to run since the dag is in the dags folder and we should not put it in the path.

But when I try to open the testscript.sql and read its contents it's necessary that I put "dags" in the path (dags/testdag/testscript.sql). Why does the path behave differently when using the MsSqlOperator and the open-function?

For convenience I put the whole script in this post:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator
from datetime import datetime

with DAG(
    dag_id = "testdag",
    schedule_interval="30 6 * * *",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    catchup=False) as dag:

    # Error because of missing connection - this is how it should be
    first_task = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id="first_task",
        sql="testdag/testscript.sql")
    
    # Error because of template not found
    second_task = MsSqlOperator(
        task_id="second_task",
        sql="dags/testdag/testscript.sql")

    # When trying to open the file the path has to contain "dags" in the path - why?
    with open("dags/testdag/testscript.sql","r") as file:
        f = file.read()
        file.close()

    first_task
    second_task
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MsSqlOperator` has [`sql`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/20499984f183e0630b41560b68a60fc1511c92f2/airflow/providers/microsoft/mssql/operators/mssql.py#L51) as templated field. This means that Jinja engine will run on the string passed via the `sql` parameter. Moreover it has `.sql` as [templated extension](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/20499984f183e0630b41560b68a60fc1511c92f2/airflow/providers/microsoft/mssql/operators/mssql.py#L52). This means that the operator knows to open `.sql` file, read it content and pass it via the Jinja engine before submitting it to the MsSQL db for execution. The behavior that you are seeing is part of Airflow power. You don't need to write code to read the query from the file. Airflow does that for you. Airflow asks you just to provide the query string and the connection - The rest is on the Operator to handle.

The:

```
second_task = MsSqlOperator(
    task_id="second_task",
    sql="dags/testdag/testscript.sql")
```

is throwing template not found error since Airflow knows to look for template extensions in paths relative to your DAG. This path is not relative to your DAG. If you want this path to be available then use template_searchpath as:

```
with DAG(
    ...,
    template_searchpath=["dags/testdag/"],
) as dag:
```

Then your operator can just have `sql=testscript.sql`

As for the:

```
with open("dags/testdag/testscript.sql","r") as file:
    f = file.read()
    file.close()
```

This practically do nothing. The file will be opened and read from the scheduler as this is a top level code. Not only that - these lines will be executed every 30 seconds (default of [min_file_process_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval) as Airflow periodically scans your `.py` file searching for DAG updates. This should also answer your question why `dags/` is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the explanation! I understood it & will change my code accordingly. If it doesnt bother you I'd have a follow up question:
As you mentioned the opened file does nothing here. In my real world example it opens a json file, converts it into a dictionary and uses it as arguments for a looped operator call. Since I have many arguments in this dictionary it would make the function messy. Do you think I should keep a dictionary in front of the function or is importing the json file okay computational wise (_top level code_)? The latter would keep the DAG more readable.

Comment: That is a very diffrent question. I suggest you will open a new one with code samples

Comment: you're right. i opened this new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306069/airflow-using-external-json-files-for-operator-arguments-in-a-dag

Answer (score 1):

Using the `template_searchpath` will work as @Elad has mentioned, but this is DAG-specific.

To find files in Airflow without using `template_searchpath`, remember that everything Airflow runs starts in the $AIRFLOW_HOME directory (i.e. `airflow` by default, or wherever you're executing the services from). So either start there with all your imports, or reference them in relation to the code file you're currently in (i.e. `current_dir` from my previous answer).

Setting Airflow up for the first time can be fiddly.